# How does a macro like #define DCL_PROP(prop) work?

Tags: c++

Recently, I got some brand new code to me during my work, and I'm confused about how those code worked out. After searching and only to find out little information, I came here for help.

So here comes the code:

```
#define DCL_PROP(prop) \  
private: \  
    std::string prop; \  
public: \  
    User& set_##prop(const std::string& prop) \  
    { \  
        this->prop = prop; \  
        return *this; \  
    } \  
    const std::string& get_##prop() \  
    { \  
        return prop; \  
    }
```

What does it mean?

Comment: google c++ macro and learn it

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After that `#define`, wherever `DCL_PROP(`prop`)` appears inside a class, the test listed in the macro will be injected into the C++ code, adding a private data member called whatever you supplied for "prop", with public `set_`prop and `get_`prop functions.  For example:

```
class X
{
    DCL_PROP(name);
};
```

Would generate code like this:

```
class X
{
private:
    std::string prop;
public:
    User& set_name(const std::string& prop)
    {
        this->prop = prop;
        return *this;
    }
    const std::string& get_name()
    {
        return prop;
    }
};
```

...except that it'll all be on one line in the generated code, which is of no functional relevance.

You can normally observe these kind of substitutions using a compile switch, for example: `g++ -E somefile.cc` or `cl.exe /E somefile.cpp`.

Comment: And the use of  return type `User &` is curious; it is not clear why the only class this can be used in is `class User` (when the class name could have been provided as an argument to the macro), but it allows the author to write a single line for each property, and to generate a setter and a getter for the property.  (Or, in other words, while I agree with most of what you said, the `class X` must be `class User` or the macro must be upgraded.)

Comment: Thx for your detailed explaination.but I still got one question, what's the advantage/disadvantage of macros like this

Comment: Well spotted - I didn't look that carefully.  Still, it could be used for not only `User`, but any class derived from `User`... maybe that was considered a useful sanity-check /restriction for the intended usage.  Bit tacky though, as many uses of macros are.

Comment: @Markowitz: the advantage is you can factor the code better - writing less lines and having less redundancy.  Then you can change the macro and "fix" or tweak all the uses to which it's put.  The disadvantage is that macros are evil for various reasons you'll see explained in the C++ FAQ lite (google it).